# How to create a clean postgres DB for testing with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I use it in postgres for system development.

When testing, I would like to create a clean DB and proceed with the test based on it. Is it possible with postgres?

In the case of sqlite, it is possible to create a temporary database by coding as follows.

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///./test_temp.db', echo=False)

_session_factory = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
)
```

How can I achieve this with postgres?

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763336/) to allow creation of temporary database.

Comment: thank you. I decided to use [this library](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql)